# Why is list.size()>0 slower than list.isEmpty() in Java?

Tags: java, list

Why is `list.size()>0` slower than `list.isEmpty()` in Java? On other words why `isEmpty()` is preferable over `size()>0`?

When I look at the implementation in `ArrayList`, then it looks like the speed should be the same:

**ArrayList.size()**

```
    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in this list.
     *
     * @return the number of elements in this list
     */
    public int size() {
      return size;
    }
```

**ArrayList.isEmpty()**

```
    /**
     * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list contains no elements.
     *
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contains no elements
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
     }
```

If we just write a simple program to get the time take by both the methods, that case `size()` will take more `isEmpty()` in all cases, why this so?

Here is my TestCode;

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l=new Vector();
        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
            l.add(new Integer(i).toString());
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        Long sTime=System.nanoTime();
        l.size();
        Long eTime=System.nanoTime();
        l.isEmpty();
        Long eeTime=System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(eTime-sTime);
        System.out.println(eeTime-eTime);
    }
}
```

Here `eTime-sTime>eeTime-eTime` in all cases. Why?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Your testing code is flawed.

Just reverse the order, i.e call isEmpty first and size > 0 second and you'll get the *opposite* result. This is due to class loading, caching, etc.

Comment: @JLR:Yes I accept your point,There was flaw,as tested both the methods in 2 separate  projects and both are giving,very much similar result.
Thanx for Clearing my doubt

Answer (score 107):

For `ArrayList`, yes — you are correct that the operations take (roughly) the same time.

For other implementations of `List` — for example, a naïve linked list* — counting the size might take a very long time, while you only actually care whether it is greater than zero.

So if you absolutely know that the list is an implementation of `ArrayList` and will never ever change, then it does not really matter; but:

1. This is bad programming practice to tie yourself down to a specific implementation.
2. If things change a few years down the line with code restructuring, testing will show that "it works," but things are running less efficiently than before.
3. Even in the best case, `size() == 0` is still *not faster* than `isEmpty()`, so there is no compelling reason to ever use the former.
4. `isEmpty()` is a clearer definition of what it is you actually care about and are testing, and so makes your code a bit more easily understandable.

** I originally wrote LinkedList here, implicitly referencing `java.util.LinkedList`, though that particular implementation does store its size explicitly, making `size()` an O(1) operation here. A naïve linked list operation might not do this, and in the more general sense there is no efficiency guarantee on implementations of `List`.*

Comment: "the" `LinkedList` (a.k.a `java.util.LinkedList`) also stores its size so the `size()` call is just as fast as for `ArrayList`, but the general point is still very valid.

Comment: @dtszzs:The run time is not same,thats what i tested and just making me uncomfortable..

Comment: @Sam Rudolph: how did you test it? There are thousands of ways to get such microbenchmarks wrong.

Comment: @Joachim - yes, good point about the java.util.LinkedList, I've revised that section to be clearer.

Answer (score 17):

I'm sorry, but your benchmark is flawed. Take a look at [Java theory and practice: Anatomy of a flawed microbenchmark](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225.html) for a general description on how to approach benchmarks.

---

*Update*: for a proper benchmark you should look into [JApex](http://japex.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 10):

.size() has to look at the entire list, while .isEmpty() can stop at the first one.

Obviously implementation dependent, but as has been said before, if you don't need to know the actual size, why bother counting all the elements?

Answer (score 6):

You said:

> Here `eTime-sTime>eeTime-eTime` in all cases Why?

First off, it's probably because of your testing code. You can't test the speed of calling l.size() and l.isEmpty() at the same time, since they both query the same value. Most likely calling l.size() has loaded the size of your list into your cpu cache and calling l.isEmpty() is a lot faster as a result.

You could try calling l.size() a couple of million times and l.isEmpty() a couple of million times in *two separate programs* but in theory the compiler could just optimize away all those calls since you're not actually doing anything with the results.

In any case, the performance difference between the two will be negligible, especially once you do the comparison you need to do to see if the list is empty (`l.size() == 0`). Most likely the generated code will look almost completely similar. As some other posters noted, you want to optimize for readability in this case, not speed.

edit: I tested it myself. It's pretty much a toss-up. `size()` and `isEmpty()` used on `Vector` gave differing results on long runs, neither beat the other consistently. When run on an `ArrayList` `size()` seemed faster, but not by much. This is most likely due to the fact that access to `Vector` is synchronized, so what you're really seeing when trying to benchmark access to these methods is synchronisation overhead, which can be very sensitive.

The thing to take away here is that when you're trying to optimize a method call with a couple nanoseconds difference in execution time, then you're **doing it wrong**. Get the basics right first, like using `Long`s where you should be using `long`.

Comment: no actually just not i ran the two cases in separate  programs just to Clear the doubt and result is same size() is taking 10 times more runtime than isEmpty()

Answer (score 2):

Counting items in a linked list can be very slow.

Comment: @spdenme:but its not counting,its just returning a value?

Comment: In your example you have an *ArrayList*

Comment: List is an interface. How it is implemented affects the relative performance of those two methods. Since size() is a frequently called method, most implementations decide the cost of maintaing a size field is worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Given those two implementations, the speed should be the same, that much is true.

But those are by far not the only possible implementations for these methods. A primitive linked list (one that doesn't store the size separately) for example could answer `isEmpty()` much faster than a `size()` call.

More importantly: `isEmpty()` describes your intent exactly, while `size()==0` is unnecessarily complex (not hugely complex of course, but any unnecessary complexity at all should be avoided).

Comment: but6 if u see there implementation,those looks very very simple?

Comment: The ones you look at, yes. But as @dtsazza explained pretty well: implementation is not the only important thing, intent and readability are important as well. And there might be other Collectons implementations where `size()` might not be implemented so easily (`WeakHashMap` or other dynamic collections).

Answer (score 1):

According to PMD ( static ruleset based Java source code analyzer ) isEmpty() is preferred.
You can find the PMD ruleset here. Search for "UseCollectionIsEmpty" rule.

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/design.html

According to me it also helps in keeping the entire source code consistent rather than half of the folks using isEmpty() and the rest using size()==0.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say in general which is faster, because it depends on which implementation of interface `List` you are using.

Suppose we're talking about `ArrayList`. Lookup the source code of `ArrayList`, you can find it in the file **src.zip** in your JDK installation directory. The source code of the methods `isEmpty` and `size` looks as follows (Sun JDK 1.6 update 16 for Windows):

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

You can easily see that both expressions `isEmpty()` and `size() == 0` will come down to exactly the same statements, so one is certainly not faster than the other.

If you're interested in how it works for other implementations of interface `List`, look up the source code yourself and find out.