# boolean changing when its condition has changed?

Tags: java

```
boolean listIsEmpty = myList.size()==0;
```

Will `listIsEmpty` change to false as soon as the size of `myList` changes of is this a one-time assignment?
If the latter, can I have a 'dynamic' boolean that 'watches' `myList?`

Comment: Please note that `.isEmpty()` is more efficient than `size() == 0`.

Comment: @UwePlonus Is it really?

Comment: @UwePlonus It may be clearer, but seriously? You're claiming that there's actually a performance improvement? You'll have to back that up with a source.

Comment: `isEmpty` vs `size` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341740/ifliststr-size-0-versus-ifliststr-isempty

Comment: @Karna That answer is patently wrong.

Comment: boolean is a primitive type thus it stores a value and NOT a reference.

Comment: Spoilers: [`LinkedList.size()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.size%28%29), [`AbstractCollection.isEmpty()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.isEmpty%28%29) which is inherited in `LinkedList`. `LinkedList` keeps track of the item count explicitly - and in fact, it's possible for pretty much every common collection type to do so. This means that `isEmpty()` is (theoretically) **slower** because of the extra call.

Comment: Of course in reality it makes no difference either way, whats more important is readability

Comment: @RichardTingle Except that "readability" is subjective, when people say "this is more readable" they tend to mean "this is what I'm used to" or "this is what I like more". Consider that .NET doesn't have an equivalent of `isEmpty()`, the convention there is to use `x.Count == 0`. Does that make the code unreadable? Hardly. Does it make the code "less readable"? How do you quantify that? (I admit I might have a peeve here, having experienced too many debates over minutiae of style that amounted to little else than people airing out their control issues.)

Comment: @millimoose Of course, frankly I think they're both as readable as each other and I don't mind which one people use. What I'm saying is that if the performance difference (if it even exists) is a billionth of the total program run time then the only rational debate you can have is over readability and and performance difference is being used as a proxy war for opinions people actually have based on readability

Comment: @RichardTingle So, basically, there's no rational debate in sight when you're discussing differences this tiny.

Comment: @millimoose For interest only its interesting, but I wouldn't base what to actually do on it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple answers: no and no.

The expression is evaluated once and then the result in your `boolean` will not change.

To have such a 'dynamic' `boolean` you have to create your own list with a listener that will achieve his.

Answer (score 3):

No, because this is not defining a mathematical relationship, it is defining a set of instructions.  After the instructions are executed, one cannot expect `listIsEmpty` to automaically update.

To do automatic updates, look into the "Listener Pattern".

To write this condition in a more sensible manner, it is the List's responsibility to know if it is empty, which is why it contains an `isEmpty()` method.  Instead of caching this information and acting on the cache, delegate the request.

```
if (myList.isEmpty()) {
  ... do stuff ...
}
```

Will prevent the cache from returning a stale view of the list's emptiness.

Answer (score 2):

Your `listIsEmpty` won't change unless you go over this specific line of code again

To have your boolean change as soon as your list size increases, should make a method that checks your list size whenever you add or remove something.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean listIsEmpty() {
    return myList.isEmpty();
}
```

A variable assignment is evaluated at that spot.

Using a function like above, `if (listIsEmpty()) { ... }` evaluates the function (method) body everytime.

Comment: Why do you want to wrap this in yet another method call?  That's adding another layer unnecessarily.

Comment: Much better Joop, this makes sense now

Comment: @Makoto but the question was, whether an expression can be named and using the name reevaluated.

Comment: I disagree.  The question seemed more like they wanted a way to dynamically check the size of the list, and `myList.isEmpty()` more than accomplishes that without the need to wrap it in a method call.

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is written now, it won't change until the size is re-evaluated.  But, instead of doing that, you can use the [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty%28%29) check directly on your list; this way, you don't have to constantly monitor the list's size.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ListisEmpty` varible is not gonna change untill you change it yourself. you have to update your `ListIsempty` variable each time you update your `Mylist` ,

Comment: I deleted my now inapplicable comment.