# Which is better? isEmpty() or size() == 0?

Tags: java

I'm wondering why there's an isEmpty() method in Java's List interface since there's a size() method. And when used as a loop guard, which one is better, list.isEmpty() or list.size == 0?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: I seem to recall a duplicate, the implementation of isEmpty() was return size==0; in the oracle implementation.

Comment: In terms of performance? Readability? Or in terms of some other criteria?

Comment: In some implementations, isEmpty is cheaper than size - a linked list, for example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508975/why-is-list-size0-slower-than-list-isempty-in-java

Comment: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/design.html#UseCollectionIsEmpty

Comment: Semantics makes the difference here if ( stuffs.isEmpty() ) conveys a lot more meaning than == 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they are the same :

```
 public boolean isEmpty() {
     return size == 0;
 }

 public int size() {
     return size;
 }
```

Comment: Do you recall the duplicate Q?

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of `List.isEmpty()` actually tests for `List.size() == 0`. That being said the JVM can easily optimize this method and it is best to use `List.isEmpty()` over `List.size() == 0` for clarity purposes.