# Understanding the difference between Collection.isEmpty() and Collection.size() == 0?

Tags: java, performance, collections, size, is-empty

I have read so many article as on difference between `isEmpty()` and `size()` > 0 for check that `collection` is empty or not and found that `isEmpty()` have perfomance over `size()` but I could not understand easily why perfomance of `isEmpty()` is good even though inside isEmpty() is only size == 0 ?

My **questions** are :

1. Can any one explain easily in which scenario `isEmpty()` is faster as well as when to use `isEmpty()` and `size()` function for checking if `collection` is `empty` or not?
2. Can any one explain this, using code or other way(Diagrams,graphs etc) so that any beginner can understand easily?

Comment: Hope you have checked:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152536/check-if-a-collection-is-empty-in-java-which-is-the-best-method

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341740/ifliststr-size-0-versus-ifliststr-isempty

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508975/why-is-list-size0-slower-than-list-isempty-in-java

Comment: Thanks @Pam but I had already read this articles but not getting the exact difference as well as how **O(1) and O(n)** is calculated in terms of performance.

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya you might want to read about complexity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it

Comment: I've edited my answer now to give you an example of a standard JDK collection that's constant-time for `isEmpty()` and linear for `size()`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon This isn't a duplicate of either of the tagged questions. Both of those talk about *lists* specifically, rather than *collections* in general (despite the title of the second one).

Comment: Thank you very much @MihaiC , I am reading that article but question is that `isEmpty()` function call internally `size()` function so how can possible that difference in  performance?

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya no, `isEmpty()` is not *always* internally just a `size()` call. See my answer for an example of where it isn't.

Answer (score 11):

It might be that *some* collections just use `size()==0` inside their `isEmpty()` method, but that doesn't mean that they all do. The default implementation of `isEmpty()` just checks whether `size() == 0`, but a particular collection is free to override this with something else if it's more efficient.

Here's a nice example. The [`ConcurrentSkipListSet` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) says:

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, the size method is not a constant-time operation.

For this class, you'd certainly want to use `isEmpty()` rather than `size() == 0`.

(To understand why it's true for a skip list, you'd need to read up on how skip lists work, but do come back and ask another question about them if you want to know more.)

Comment: LinkedList's implementation of size() doesn't traverse the list, but rather keeps track of size when the list is modified.

Comment: @Martin yes, I've just added something about this. This is why I'd written "linked list" rather than `LinkedList`. The standard implementation keeps track of the size, but that's not to say that every collection *must* do this.

Comment: @Martin I've deleted the linked list example and replaced with a clear and concrete example.

Answer (score 6):

Basically I had found that
`.size()` can be **O(1)** or **O(N)**, depending on the `data structure`; `.isEmpty()` is never **O(N)**.

Comment: AbstractCollection : `public boolean isEmpty() {
 return size() == 0;
    }`. Which means size() and isEmpty() have the same complexity in all the major collections

Comment: you just copied one answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341740/ifliststr-size-0-versus-ifliststr-isempty , just point the OP to that question ...

Comment: @MihaiC I told that I had read it from stack overflow itself but this doesnot mean that it has the copy right. :)

Comment: @Eran in major `collections` but not in all collections you take look on `linkedlist` implementation.

Comment: @BhargavModi LinkedList extends AbstractSequentialList which extends AbstractList which extends AbstractCollection, so LinkedList has the same implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The top reasons for using **isEmpty** rather than **size** would be:

```
it is more expressive (the code is easier to read and to maintain)

it is faster, in some cases by orders of magnitude.
```

Detailed explanation [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/reasons-call-isempty)

**++** same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508975/why-is-list-size0-slower-than-list-isempty-in-java)

Comment: Thanks @ankur-singhal , I am agree with your answer but currently i am focusing on difference on **performance** rather than code style or maintenance.

Comment: Performance-wise, `isEmpty()` may *allow* an implementation to do some optimization compared to `size()`. However, if and to what extend `isEmpty()` is performance-optimized is completely up to the specific implementation class used. I think the only thing one can rely on is that `O(isEmpty) <= O(size)`. Hence, using `isEmpty` does make for more expressive code and is kind of a best effort on performance.